# How Can I Manage Dynamics Config constant change?

Tags: php, laravel

How to change theme setting Config variables in Laravel?

```
return [

    'ACTIVE_FLAG' => 'active',
    'INACTIVE_FLAG' => 'inactive',
    'DELETED_FLAG' => 'deleted',
]
```

Actually, I want to update the "ACTIVE_FLAG" variable from my database. so How can I?

Comment: Just use a model if you want data sourced from a database, don't use Laravel's config implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage AppServiceProvider in get data from using model

```
$getThemeSetting = YOURMODELNAME::get();
Config::set('constant.ACTIVE_FLAG' , $getThemeSetting['active_flag']);
```